# Сортировка вектора указателей

Tags: c++

Есть вектор указателей на объекты класса. Как выполнить его сортировку по одному из полей этого класса при помощи функции сравнения? Как она должна выглядеть?

```
std::vector<MyClassScan*> scanArray;
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

### Сортировка

Как выглядит функция сравнения — это известно только вам, данных о структуре `MyClassScan` вы не предоставляете.

Как сортировать? Очень просто, нужно использовать [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort) или подобный алгоритм. Сигнатуру вызова можно найти по ссылке.

### Функция сравнения

Теперь, как написать правильный компаратор (функцию сравнения). Такая функция принимает на вход два объекта и возвращает `true`, если один больше/меньше другого (бинарное отношение). К примеру, `std::less` задает отношение «меньше»:

```
auto less = std::less<int>();
std::cout << less(1, 0) << "\n";  // 0
std::cout << less(1, 1) << "\n";  // 0
std::cout << less(0, 1) << "\n";  // 1
```

Как написать такую функцию, думаю, понятно. Нужно лишь учитывать, что вы работаете с указателями, которые могут быть нулевыми. Что делать, если на вход подали такой указатель — решать вам.

Пример:

```
struct Test { int val = 0; };

bool cmp_test(const Test* a, const Test* b) {
    return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val < b->val;
}

int main() {
    Test a, b;
    a.val = 0; b.val = 1;
    std::cout << cmp_test(b, a) << "\n";  // 0
    std::cout << cmp_test(b, b) << "\n";  // 0
    std::cout << cmp_test(a, b) << "\n";  // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Или используя лямбды:

```
struct Test { int val = 0; };

int main() {
    auto cmp_test = [](const Test* a, const Test* b) {
        return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val < b->val;
    };
    Test a, b;
    a.val = 0; b.val = 1;
    std::cout << cmp_test(b, a) << "\n";  // 0
    std::cout << cmp_test(b, b) << "\n";  // 0
    std::cout << cmp_test(a, b) << "\n";  // 1
    return 0;
}
```

### Функтор сравнения

На этом месте нужно задать вопрос: почему мы писали `auto less = std::less<int>();`? А именно, зачем круглые скобки и что же такое std::less?

Рассмотрим типичную функцию, использующую компаратор. К примеру, минимум:

```
template<typename T, class CMP> T min(const T a, const T b, CMP cmp) {
    return cmp(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

Наша функция принимает на вход два объекта и компаратор для них и возвращает меньший объект. К примеру:

```
Test a, b;
a.val = -1; b.val = 1;
auto m = min(&a, &b, cmp_test);
std::cout << m->val << "\n";  // -1
```

Что же такое `cmp` внутри функции `min`? В нашем коде это указатель на функцию. Наша `min` принимает указатель на функцию и вызывает ее.

Но если сравнений происходит много (а в сортировке их много), мы будем терять немного времени на вызов функции. Значит, мы хотим сделать нашу функцию inline.

Проблема в том, что указатель на функцию мы заранее не знаем, а значит не можем инлайнить реализацию. К примеру, у нас может быть два компаратора с одинаковой сигнатурой, и мы можем передать ссылку на любой из них:

```
auto cmp_test1 = [](const Test* a, const Test* b) {
    return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val < b->val;
};

auto cmp_test2 = [](const Test* a, const Test* b) {
    return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val > b->val;
};

    ...

Test a, b;
a.val = -1; b.val = 1;
auto m1 = min(&a, &b, cmp_test1);
auto m2 = min(&a, &b, cmp_test2);
std::cout << m1->val << "\n";  // -1
std::cout << m2->val << "\n";  // 1
```

В коде выше шаблонизатор вывел одну спецификацию шаблона `min`, которая принимает указатель на функцию.

Поэтому применяется трюк в виде функтора.
Функтор — структура с определенным оператором `operator()`. Такая структура выглядит, как функция, но на самом деле это класс. Рассмотрим `std::less`:

```
template <class T> struct less : binary_function <T, T, bool> {
    bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const { return x < y; }
};
```

Итак, мы создали структуру `less` (наследование от `binary_function`, вообще, не обязательно, см. комментарий @alexolut). Экземпляры структуры ведут себя похожим на функцию образом — их можно «вызывать»:

```
auto cmp = less<int>();  // Создаем экземпляр структуры
std::cout << cmp(1, 0) << "\n";  // 0  // Используем operator()
std::cout << cmp(1, 1) << "\n";  // 0
std::cout << cmp(0, 1) << "\n";  // 1
```

Чем это кардинально отличается от указателя на функцию? А тем, что для каждой такой структуры шаблонизатор выведет свою спецификацию. Мы можем использовать такие структуры точно так же, как и функции:

```
Test a, b;
a.val = -1; b.val = 1;
auto m = min(&a, &b, less<int>());
std::cout << m->val << "\n";  // -1
```

Однако теперь мы передаем внутрь не указатель на некоторую функцию, а экземпляр конкретного класса. А значит, реализация `operator()` известна для каждой спецификации и ее можно заинлайнить.

Для нашего `Test` такой функтор будет выглядить так:

```
struct cmp_test3 : binary_function <Test*, Test*, bool> {
    bool operator() (const Test* a, const Test* b) const {
        return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val < b->val;
    }
};
```

### TLDR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Test {
    int val = 0;
    Test(int a): val(a) {};
};

struct cmp_test : std::binary_function <Test*, Test*, bool> {
    bool operator() (const Test* a, const Test* b) const {
        return !a || !b ? 0 : a->val < b->val;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a(1), b(3), c(2), d(4);
    std::vector<Test*> v {&a, &b, &c, &d};

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp_test());

    for (auto i: v)
        std::cout << i->val << " ";  // 1 2 3 4

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::binary_function` признана устаревшей в `c++11`. В `c++17` будет исключена вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyClassScan
{
    int sortedField;
    int otherField;

    MyClassScan(int _sortedField, int _otherField)
    : sortedField(_sortedField)
    , otherField(_otherField)
    {}
};

bool ComparatorFunction(const MyClassScan* left, const MyClassScan* right)
{
    return left->sortedField < right->sortedField;
}

struct ComparatorClass
{
    bool operator () (const MyClassScan* left, const MyClassScan* right) const
    {
        return left->sortedField < right->sortedField;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClassScan*> pointersVector = { new MyClassScan(5, 1), new MyClassScan(4, 2), new MyClassScan(3, 3), new MyClassScan(2, 4), new MyClassScan(1, 5) };

    // способ 1
    std::sort(pointersVector.begin(), pointersVector.end(), [](const MyClassScan* left, const MyClassScan* right){ return left->sortedField < right->sortedField; });

    // способ 2
    std::sort(pointersVector.begin(), pointersVector.end(), ComparatorFunction);

    // способ 3
    std::sort(pointersVector.begin(), pointersVector.end(), ComparatorClass());

    for (auto it = pointersVector.begin(); it != pointersVector.end();)
    {
        delete *(it++);
    }
}
```

---

При необходимости добавьте везде проверки на `nullptr`.

Если возникнет необходимость сотировать сразу по нескольким полям класса, то воспользуйтесь `std::tie` в соответствующих местах:

```
std::tie(left->sortedField, left->otherField) < std::tie(right->sortedField, right->otherField)
```

вместо

```
left->sortedField < right->sortedField
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто:

```
std::sort(begin(scanArray), end(scanArray), [](const MyClassScan* a, const MyClassScan *b) {
  return a->someField < b->someField;
});
```

Если более обще: то просто передать свой компаратор в алгоритм `std::sort`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort